# Math education/visualisation tools for university level

Tags: self-learning, math-software, visualization

I'm looking for a programs that helps learning ( getting familiar with math concepts) - that is not the programs that will help you practice it, but rather programs which will create the certain intuition, and I'm talking about university level in math major. I know wolfram, it's a fine tool, but it's not focused on visual understanding.(so any matlab, octave or sage doesn't fall into that category either) And please make note - i'm not talking about statistical visualition to present data to someone or something like that. For example i've been looking for a real time conformal mapping drawer and couldn't find anything satisfying.

I fell in love with [3Blue1Brown](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYO_jab_esuFRV4b17AJtAw) visualisations and it seems like there should be some inventions which have solo-learning of the concept as a primary reason of existence rather then presenting the data patterns to bussiness people.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't have any programming skills, or if your programming skills are not very good, I can only recommend you geogebra.
3blue1brown is really the master of mathematical visualisation and animation, he wrote a Python program to do all the animations for the videos, you can find the program on github (the github repository is referenced on his website), but unless you have a lot of time and your programming skills are really good you won't be able to use this software.
I've just seen that you asked all this more than a year ago, have you found or developed a better solution since then?

Greetings from Göttingen
Dominik